# Loading an mp4 video from an html link on Android

Tags: android, html, video, hyperlink

I have a html file on my Samsung android tablet that has a link like this:

```
<a href="./video/0001_a1.mp4" target="_blank">Click to play local 0001_a1.mp4</a>
```

When I click it I wanted it to open the video file that is in the sub directory /video beneath but only the link background changes like the link is being pressed but no video plays.  If I remove the video file and press the link I get an error that it can't find the file.  So I know that something is trying to happen.   I have also tried

```
<a href="video/0001_a1.mp4" target="_blank">Click to play local 0001_a1.mp4</a>
```

With the same results.  Both work fine when on a Windows PC.

How can I load local videos using an html link on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mobile browsers you must call `window.open` inside onClick instead of set `href` attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('./video/0001_a1.mp4','_blank')">
    Click to play local 0001_a1.mp4
</a>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion... clicking refreshes the current page window to the top... it does not open a new window playing the video.

Comment: How do you open your html page? chrome or webview inside app?

Comment: I just clicked on the html file to open the page and it by default opened in the Android HTMLViewer.  I don't seem to be able to change defaults to open the html file in Chrome.

Comment: Why to to use <video> tag?